# Kendo UI Editor Style all paragraphs in body

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I need to update the top and bottom margins for paragraphs within the Kendo editor to make the spacing between the lines smaller.  I updated the style file as below, but the paragraph lines still have the same spacing.

```
.k-content body p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

What else should I change to see the results I am looking for?  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try line-height: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: Unfortunately changing line-height doesn't work for me.  I need to do this through style change, but the style that I have mentioned is not working.

Comment: I was able to style the paragraphs in the content of the Kendo Editor using the information in these helpful links:    https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/styles        https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/editors/editor/styling

Answer (score 1):

I was able to style the paragraphs in the content of the Kendo Editor using the information in the two below links.  They show the default styles for Kendo Editor and also how to create a custom stylesheet and refer to it in the editor:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/styles

https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/editors/editor/styling